# Woocomerce Change/Edit Endoint URL

Tags: woocommerce, urlvariables

I am working on the "My account" page on wordpress (woocommerce). I need **a hook** to edit the URL enpoint for "Account variables". I know I can change this variables in Woocommerce->Settings->the Advance, however, I can not edit the new variables for example:

/my-account/edit-address/ if I click on the "edit" link to change the shipping address, the url changes to /my-account/edit-address/shipping. I would like to change it to /my-account/edit-address/shipping/#edit-zone, I am adding #edit-zone. I tried with a redirectioning plugin, but it responds with an error that says: *the anchor is not sent in the request and is not received by the server. You will need to do any redirections on the client using JavaScript.*

Any ideas?

I tried to do this with a plugin, however, I believe there should be a hook I can paste on my child them using a snippet.